# JComboBox to get information from the internet

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jcombobox

I want to make a program that when a user chooses a location, it will show the address of different places of interest below the combo box. For example, when the user chooses London, it will list down address of places of interest in London only. And when the user chooses another location it will show the different addresses in that location only. Instead of writing down the addresses one by one, how do I connect it the internet to automatically get the addresses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the content of a page easily using an URLConnection.
If you've got a handy-dandy online API or something to handle the rest, you can easily get a page's content like this:

```
public static String getSource(String link){
    try{
        URL u = new URL(link);
        URLConnection con = u.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            buffer.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
        return buffer.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

keep in mind you might want to call this in a thread, as it will take some time to load the page.